# Strip RTF tags from a string

Tags: php, regex

Does anyone know of any library's or Regex pattern that could string a string of all RTF tags?  For example, with the following string:

```
{\field\flddirty{\*\fldinst ref {\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \b\insrsid11370280\charrsid4074187  MERG}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \b\insrsid15665935 
\par }{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \b\insrsid11370280\charrsid4074187 EFIELD details_awardee_name }}{\fldrslt {\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \b\lang1024\langfe1024\noproof\insrsid11370280\charrsid4074187 \'abdetails_awardee_name\'bb}}}
```

This should be stripped down to `MERGEFIELD details_awardee_name`?

Comment: Curious: where is this input coming from and what is it used for?

Comment: Not tested: http://webcheatsheet.com/php/reading_the_clean_text_from_rtf.php

Comment: Wesley, this is a follow up question to a previous thread I started, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224587/find-coresponding-open-close-brackets/

Comment: @jason Please include all relevant information in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't know the rules to parse (RTF's) thier nested tags, I just post this, which seems to
filter some of the clutter.

```
   # Raw:        \\[^\s]*\s*|[{}]+\s*
   # Delimited:  '/\\\[^\s]*\s*|[{}]+\s*/'

   \\ [^\s]* \s* 
|  [{}]+ \s*
```

Perl test case -

```
$/ = undef;
$str = <DATA>;

$str =~ s/\\[^\s]*\s*|[{}]+\s*//g;

print "'$str'\n";

__DATA__
{\field\flddirty{\*\fldinst ref {\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \b\insrsid11370280\charrsid4074187  MERG}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \b\insrsid15665935 
\par }{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \b\insrsid11370280\charrsid4074187 EFIELD details_awardee_name }}{\fldrslt {\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \b\lang1024\langfe1024\noproof\insrsid11370280\charrsid4074187 \'abdetails_awardee_name\'bb}}}
```

Output >>

```
'ref MERGEFIELD details_awardee_name '
```

Comment: Thanks.  In PHP, it was converted to something like:  preg_replace('/\\\\[^\\s]*\\s*|[{}]+\\s*/', '', $foundString);